# Writing data to MySQL from Kafka consumer using StreamSets

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, streamsets

I am trying to write data from Kafka consumer to MySQL using JDBC. I am able to take data from databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL using JDBC but not able to write the data to a database. However I am able to write the data to a text file.

What am I missing or should do?

Comment: What exactly are the errors you get? Also, have you tried using Kafka Connect JDBC?

Comment: Error Code: 1109
Message: Unknown table 'data' in information_schema. This I found in log when I`m trying to write data to a mysql database from a local csv file. The only problem is this error no matter how I try to write into a mysql database.

Comment: `information_schema` is the default database. What's the actual database you're trying to insert into? Obviously `data` is the table name, but you can must use `db.data` for a given `db` database

Comment: I've made a student database and inside it a table named data.

Comment: Okay, can you please share your Streamsets configuration properties with an [edit] to the question?

Comment: I would like to mention that Kafka Connect can be used to send data to databases as well.

Comment: With kafla connect? Without jdbc? Can you please provide me any doc link for that?

Comment: With JDBC. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html Note: It does not require Confluent installed Kafka, you can check out a release branch and build from https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely try that. :)